# not able to automate drop down as while selecting one value gets auto picked,so second one is not visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpathnavigator

I am trying to automate below website drop down:

https://qa.roofandfloor.com/

In the city section,we have both bangalore and chennai,suppose bangalore gets autoselected,so running below code is failing:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='city-dropdown-search form-city hide select2-offscreen']"));
    Select se=new Select(element);
    se.selectByIndex(2);
```

its not able to recognise second city,please help me whats wrong I am doing here.

html tag is as below:

```
<select id="combobox2" class="city-dropdown-search form-city hide select2-  offscreen" name="city" tabindex="-1">
 <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
<option selected="" value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
</select>
```

is there problem with xpath or something else I am missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually type in that as below using `sendKeys()`

```
WebElement toElement = driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_combobox2"));
toElement.click();
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-drop")).sendKeys("Bangalore");
```

Here you can pass on if you have more cities by just changing the value in `sendKeys()`

Comment: little modification in your given code :

WebElement toElement = Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='s2id_combobox2']/a/span[2]"));toElement.click();
  WebElement el=Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='select2-drop']/div/input"));
    el.sendKeys("Chennai");
    el.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

it works perfectly,thanks for providing pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `text()` property in xpath to select the the 'Chennai' option by text() as below:

`//a/span[text() = 'Chennai']`

```
//click on the drop down
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_combobox2']/a/span[@class='select2-arrow']"));
dropDown.click();

//Select the dropdown value
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[text() = 'Chennai']"));
select.click();
```

Comment: that is fine,bt suppose somebody has selected chennai,then i hv to modify code & also if there are 100's entry,my code will keep on changing,any generic way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

@Arun Gupta
To make your code generic, Instead of hardcoding the city name, you can do the following

1. create an array of city names, pass it to the cityName variable
2. store citynames in excel file or text file, read each city and pass it to the cityName variable

Example for 1

```
String[] cityName = {"bangalore", "chennai", "pune"};

for(String name : cityName) {
WebElement toElement = driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_combobox2"));
toElement.click();
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-drop")).sendKeys(cityName);
}
```

Hope it helps